# Using MERGE with XMLQUERY and transform

Tags: merge, db2, xquery

Using DB2 LUW 10.1.  I am having trouble getting MERGE to work on two tables with XML columns that are merged using an XQUERY transform.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
create table foo (
  id int not null primary key,
  data xml not null
)
```

To get data into this table, I load it (using LOAD) into a staging table that looks like this:

```
create table foo_incoming (
  id int not null,
  data xml not null
)
```

The data in the XML columns is merged using an XQUERY transform.  There's some logic behind it so it's not straightforward, but it's not overly complicated either.  I have tested the transform using manual UPDATEs so I know it works.

I then try to merge the two tables like this:

```
merge into foo f
  using (select * from foo_incoming) i
  on (f.id = i.id)
  when matched then
    update set data = xmlquery('
        transform
          copy $out := $old
          modify ( ... )
          return $out'
        passing f.data as "old", i.data as "new")
  when not matched then
    insert (id, data) values (i.id, i.data)
```

This works perfectly when there is data in foo.  The XML column is merged exactly the way I want it to be.  But if foo is empty, I get this error:

```
SQL16084N  An assigned value in the copy clause of a transform expression is
not a sequence with exactly one item that is a node. Error QName=err:XUTY0013.
SQLSTATE=10705
```

It seems like DB2 is trying to evaluate the XQUERY even though the merge didn't match.  Thus, f.data is NULL, and the copy expression in the transform gets an empty sequence.  If I remove the entire "when matched" clause then the statement works.

What am I doing wrong?  Or is this a limitation of DB2's MERGE statement?

---

I have tried to work around this by changing the simple "when matched" to something like "when matched and (f.data is not null)" but that has no effect.  I also tried changing the XQUERY expression to something like this:

```
if($old)
then
  transform
    copy $out := $old
    ...
else ()
```

That didn't help either.  The only workaround I have found is to split the MERGE in twain.  First I would do this, to update rows that are in both foo and foo_incoming:

```
merge into foo f
  using
    (
      select q1.id, q1.data
        from foo_incoming q1 inner join foo q2
          on (q1.id = q2.id)
    ) i
  on (f.id = i.id)
  when matched then udpate ...;
```

Then this, to insert rows that are in foo_incoming but not foo:

```
merge into foo f
  using
    (
      select q1.id, q1.data
        from foo_incoming q1 left outer join foo q2
          on (q1.id = q2.id)
        where q2.id is null
    ) i
  on (f.id = i.id)
  when not matched then insert ...;
```

This works.  I would expect the performance to be abysmal, however.  And this is the sort of hack that I usually interpret as a warning sign that there's a fundamental error in my thinking.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bug in DB2 that should be fixed. The same problem has been described and discussed here:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=02fb0ba7-249d-431a-b173-e70511d3b582&ps=25

I would hope that an upcoming DB2 fixpack will resolve the problem.